# How to scroll a Grid?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a `Grid` which its `Height` can grow like this:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


<Grid Name="Grid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">

</Grid>
```

How can I scroll it up-down?

it is a windows phone 8 app.

Comment: Have you tried a scrollviewer? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202907(v=vs.105).aspx Without a more specific example of the problem (some content in your grid and the expected scrolling behavior) it's hard to tell how you want this to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can structure your grid as:

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="120" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid> 
           ***content goes here****
        </Grid>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Row="1">
            *****Put scalable content here*******
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0"> 
           ***content goes here****
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Is it possible to scroll the scrollviewer without seeing the scrollbar?

Comment: @ching - Set `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` to `Hidden`.

Comment: @keyboardP thanx, i was unaware of this thing and was searching, but thanx for VerticalScrollBarVisibility to Hidden

Answer (score 1):

In short though you're not going to scroll a grid. You are going to create a grid set to the screen size or smaller. Then put a listbox inside it. You can scroll the listbox easily because that's what it does.

```
<Grid margin="0,0,0,0" width="480" hieght="800"> <!--These values probably need ajusted-->
  <ListBox height="800"> <!--Make sure that it is ENTIRLEY on the screen -->
    <TextBlock>Put a ton of text here and see that it scrolls</TextBlock>
    <Button>You can put anything in the list boxes</Button>
    <TextBox>Even Inputs</TextBox>
  </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Another viable option that is mentioned below is a scroll viewer which works just as well.